# How to update a GUI while it's running

Tags: java, swing

So I have a JTextField displayed in a GUI. What I want to do is remove the text field when someone presses enter. I have already added ActionListener. I just want to know how to automatically update it without having to minimize it or something.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Window extends JFrame{
private JTextField TextField0;
private JTextField TextField1;
private JCheckBox CheckBox0;

//CONSTRUCTOR
public Window(){
    super("Checkbox");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    TextField0 = new JTextField("Add field",15);
    add(TextField0);
    CheckBox0 = new JCheckBox("");



    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
    TextField0.addActionListener(handler);
}
    //Method: HandlerClass
public class HandlerClass implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        if(event.getSource()==TextField0){
            CheckBox0.setText(String.format("%s",event.getActionCommand()));
        }
    }
}
}
```

*EDIT*: I figured it out guys! :D Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it lives in a container, such as a JPanel, use the `remove()` method, and ask for the panel to repaint:

```
panel.remove(textField);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at using [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).The CardLayout class manages two or more components (usually JPanel instances) that share the same display space.

Add `textField0` and `checkBox0` to 2 separate `JPanels`. In the `ActionListener` call

```
checkBox0.setText(textField0.getText());
```

Use [CardLayout#next](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#next%28java.awt.Container%29) to flip from the first to the second panel.

- [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823382/how-to-show-different-cards-in-a-cardlayout?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: And how is this helping the OP?

Comment: That worked, but i also want it to display another type of data after.

Comment: @alexdr3437 What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Reimeus I want to input something into the JTextField, then have it dissappear and display what was inputted into a JCheckBox.I already have done everything, but I want it to update instantly instead of have to minimize/maximize it.

Comment: I'm guessing you're calling remove without repaint. It would help if you posted an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) of your code to take out the guesswork.

Comment: JCheckBox? Are you sure you don't mean `JList`? Anyway see update

Comment: I was just about to, I just had to make a few changes to it first.

Comment: I am guessing I'll probably have to change it to JPanel

Answer (score 0):

You must `revalidate()` and `repaint()` the container.

Answer (score 0):

Change the declaration of the JTextField to public / private depending on how you access it:

```
public JTextField jtf = new JTextField();
```

And when you create your window:

```
jtf = new JTextField();
jtf.addActionListener {
removeJTF();
```

Use this code to remove the JTextField:

```
public void removeJTF() {

    exampleFrame.remove(jtf);
}
```