# Java, switching to specific cards not working

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, cardlayout

I am trying to make a simple app to switch between cards. I am using NetBeans 7.3 if it makes a difference. The program is also an applet.

Hopefully this question *not too specific* but I've literally just spent an entire day trying to figure this thing out and I'm at my whit's end.

Here is the code as I have it now:

My goal is to show `card2` when `Submit` is pressed.

```
package my.registerform;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Matthew
 */
public class RegisterFormUI extends javax.swing.JApplet {


     /**
     * Initializes the applet RegisterFormUI
     */
    @Override

    public void init() {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RegisterFormUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RegisterFormUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RegisterFormUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RegisterFormUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the applet */
        try {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    initComponents();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the init() method to initialize the
     * form. WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")


    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        ClearFields = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Submit = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        mainPanel.setName("mainPanel"); // NOI18N
        mainPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.CardLayout());

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Create Account")));
        jPanel1.setName("Info"); // NOI18N

        jLabel1.setText("Username:");

        jLabel2.setText("Email:");

        jLabel3.setText("Password:");

        jTextField4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel4.setText("Phone:");

        jLabel5.setText("Zip:");

        jTextField5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        ClearFields.setText("Clear Fields");
        ClearFields.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                ClearFieldsActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Submit.setText("Submit");
        Submit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                SubmitActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(14, 14, 14)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jPasswordField1)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1)))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(ClearFields)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(Submit))
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel5))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 187, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField5))))))
                .addContainerGap(15, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jPanel1Layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {jPasswordField1, jTextField4});

        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(ClearFields)
                    .addComponent(Submit))
                .addContainerGap(27, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        mainPanel.add(jPanel1, "card1");
        jPanel1.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("Info");

        jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Success"));
        jPanel2.setName("ThankYou"); // NOI18N

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setText("Thank you for registering!");

        jButton1.setText("Back & edit");

        jButton2.setText("Finish & Exit");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton2))
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                .addContainerGap(45, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(71, 71, 71)
                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)))
        );

        mainPanel.add(jPanel2, "card2");
        jPanel2.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("ThankYou");
        jPanel2.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(mainPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(mainPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );

        mainPanel.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("mainPanel");
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    private void jTextField5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void ClearFieldsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        jTextField1.setText("");
        jTextField2.setText("");
        jPasswordField1.setText("");
        jTextField4.setText("");
        jTextField5.setText("");      

    }                                           

    private void jTextField4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void SubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        CardLayout.show(mainPanel, "card2");
    }                                      

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton ClearFields;
    private javax.swing.JButton Submit;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
    private javax.swing.JPanel mainPanel;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: i don't see a CardLayout defined in your class. I don't believe you can call CardLayout statically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). Basically you need to use the `show()` method of the CardLayout:

```
CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(mainPanel.getLayout());
cl.show(mainPanel, "card2");
```

Comment: Does this belong in a new method or in an existing one? There was an important detail in my OP that I forgot to mention but I think you've figured it out, My goal is to show card2 when Submit is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

may be this would help u  this [How to show different cards in a CardLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823382/how-to-show-different-cards-in-a-cardlayout)

and in ur code u have something strange

```
 private void SubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        CardLayout.show(mainPanel, "card2");
    }
```

Im seeing that u dont follow conventions, `submitActionPerformed` should be the name of the method and CardLayout it isn't a variable in ur code  and `show()` is not a static method so u are doing something wrong

Comment: Sorry for any confusing code, trying to teach myself java over the summer, still a newbie at this. camickr's post seemed to resolve my issue. I had completely forgotten to initialize the `CardLayout` which is why my `show()` method in `SubmitActionPerformed` was not working correctly.